# How to parse Label section in Html web page via jsoup in android

Tags: android, html, parsing, jsoup

Iam developing android application and new to html, iam facing hurdel in parsing a particular element of html webpage using jsoup in android. if anybody can guide me
iam new in software developing world

Below are section which i want to parse

```
</head>
   <body onload="update_content();">
<div class="homeBox">
<br>
<div class="brdr1"> 
    <h2 id="h2Internet">LTE</h2>
</div>
    <hr>
    <div class="boxInner brdr2"> 
    <a>
    <div style="display: block;" id="Cellular">
    <span class="heading1" id="h3IntrenetConnection">LTE Status</span>
    <strong id="pSimStatus">Connected Status:</strong><br>
    <label id="lSIMStatusValue"></label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="display: none;" id="Internet_DIV">
        <strong id="pDashCurConnTime">Connection Time:</strong>
        <label id="lDashCurConnValue">00:02:30:40</label>
        <br><br>
            <div id="divEngineerInform">
                <strong id="operatingMode">Operating Mode:</strong>
                <label id="LoperMode">TDD</label>
                <br><br>  
                <strong id="pDashEngineerInform_bandTag">Operating Band:</strong>
                <label id="pDashEngineerInform_bandValue" style="margin-left:5px;">40</label>
                <br><br>
                <strong id="pDashEngineerInform_bandwidthTag">Bandwidth:</strong>
                <label id="pDashEngineerInform_bandwidthValue" style="margin-left:5px;">20MHz</label>
                <br><br>
                <strong id="pDashEngineerInform_earfcnTag">EARFCN:</strong>
                <label id="pDashEngineerInform_earfcnValue" style="margin-left:5px;">38457</label>
                <br><br>
                <strong id="pDashEngineerInform_phycellTag">Physical Cell ID:</strong>
                <label id="pDashEngineerInform_phycellValue" style="margin-left:5px;">**9**</label>
                <br><br>
                <strong id="pDashAutoApn_plmnTag">PLMN:</strong>
                <label id="pDashAutoApn_plmnValue" style="margin-left:5px;margin-bottom:5px;">**405567**</label>
                <br><br>
                <strong id="pDashAutoApn_LteApnTag">APN in Use:</strong>
                <label id="pDashAutoApn_LteApnValue" style="margin-left:5px;">**xyyuet**</label>
                <br><br>
```

I want to parse the elements in the LABEL section (which are between double star) but i cannot figure out.

Answer (score 0):

After waiting for long i got no answer,so i researched my own and found the answer,However it may be quite easy or childish but i wanna share the answer.

As i asked how to parse a particulat elemnent in Label tag despite having id its dosent have value so "*string s= element.val()*;" wont work,below are code snippet

```
<strong id="pDashAutoApn_LteApnTag">APN in Use:</strong>
<label id="pDashAutoApn_LteApnValue" style="margin-left:5px;">**xyyuet**</label>
```

so the solution is

```
htmlDocument = Jsoup.connect(htmlPageUrl).get();
Element element= htmlDocument.getElementById("lDashCurConnValue");
htmlContentInStringFormat=element.text();
```

simply i use "*element.text()*" retrive the text within label.